# Embed matplotlib in Quickly app?

Tags: python, matplotlib, embed, canonical-quickly

I am new to programming in general and Quickly as a consequence. I would like to embed a Matplotlib graph into my Quickly application. I found some examples of how to do it with general pyGTK application, but I am not sure, how to use them with Quickly...
I at least need matplotlib window to stop inactivating the main window.

I would be glad if you could help me with it and tell, what I would need to change in standard embedding code. The official example of that is [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_gtk.html) I just do not understand, how to apply it here...

I use Glade to design  the interface, Quickly uses pygobject, not pyGTK, those are the main problems.

NEW:

I have found [this](https://github.com/JackKelly/matplotlib/commit/a496ef152b497463b73689fe87e13fbbc90df913)
And also as it seems I would have to use file **init**.py here, not the main file with all my code. It looks like this:

```
# -*- Mode: Python; coding: utf-8; indent-tabs-mode: nil; tab-width: 4 -*-
'''
Some licensing information
'''
import optparse

import locale
from locale import gettext as _
locale.textdomain('chromograph')

from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=E0611

from chromograph import ChromographWindow

from chromograph_lib import set_up_logging, get_version

def parse_options():
    """Support for command line options"""
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(version="%%prog %s" % get_version())
    parser.add_option(
        "-v", "--verbose", action="count", dest="verbose",
        help=_("Show debug messages (-vv debugs chromograph_lib also)"))
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    set_up_logging(options)

def main():
    'constructor for your class instances'
    parse_options()

    # Run the application.    
    window = ChromographWindow.ChromographWindow()
    window.show()
    Gtk.main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about what you have tried?

Comment: I actually don't understand, how to try it, because in the example the program the interface in code and, as I understand, it contains only matplotlib graph space. I use Glade to design the interface.

Comment: You should add some text to your question that you are trying to get this to work with Glade as well.  The guts of that example code is lines -4 and -3, which make a gtk object out of a matplotlib figure and then add said object to the gtk interface they are building.

Comment: OK, thank you. But they show at with pyGTK and Quickly uses pygobject - will it be important?

Comment: I so much hoped to get an answer here...